# XPath - selecting node based on following sibling

Tags: xpath, qml

I have a query like this:

```
/plist/dict[1]/dict/dict/dict/key/following-sibling::dict/string[string()='Algier']
```

What I really want to select is the 'key' node (just before the following-sibling::dict) one.

The xml is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
    <key>en_GB</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Africa</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>Algeria</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>60390</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>NAME</key>
                            <string>Algier</string>
                            <key>LATITUDE</key>
                            <string>36.7500</string>
                            <key>LONGITUDE</key>
                            <string>3.0500</string>
                        </dict>
                        <key>60391</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>NAME</key>
                            <string>Some other city</string>
                            <key>LATITUDE</key>
                            <string>36.7500</string>
                            <key>LONGITUDE</key>
                            <string>3.0500</string>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

In other words, I want to select '60390' when the city name is 'Algier' or (60391 when city name is 'some other city').

I'm doing this in a QML XmlListModel.

**Updated code**
QML used:

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: container;
    width: 360
    height: 360

    function onLocationModelLoaded(){
        console.debug(weLocationModel.count);
    }

    XmlListModel{
        id: weLocationModel;
        source: "we_locations.plist";
        query: "/*/dict/dict/dict/dict/key[following-sibling::dict[1]/key[.='NAME' and following-sibling::string[1] = 'Algier']]"

        XmlRole{
            name: "cityId";
            query: "name()";
        }
        onStatusChanged: {
            if (status == XmlListModel.Ready){
                console.debug("Location Model Ready");
                container.onLocationModelLoaded();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like the nested **following-sibling** is not working. 
for example something like:

```
query: "/*/dict/dict/dict/dict/key[following-sibling::dict[1]/key[.='NAME']]"
```

Both of these always return:

```
Error XPST0003 in file:///Users/Ali/qtprojects/welocationtest-build-simulator/welocationtest.app/Contents/MacOS/welocationtest, at line 2, column 97: syntax error, unexpected ], expecting )
Error XPST0003 in file:///Users/Ali/qtprojects/welocationtest-build-simulator/welocationtest.app/Contents/MacOS/welocationtest, at line 2, column 91: syntax error, unexpected ], expecting end of file
file:///Users/Ali/qtprojects/welocationtest-build-simulator/welocationtest.app/Contents/Resources/qml/welocationtest/main.qml:17:9: QML XmlRole: invalid query: "name()"
Location Model Ready
0
```

Could it be possible QML is not following XPath standard? THe solution works in all other path editors.

Comment: Seems like QML is buggy and non-compliant...

Comment: No wonder Nokia is where it is right now. :(

Comment: I looked this over, and I agree, if QML is throwing the above errors on the given XPath expression, QML has a bug. Why in the world would it be expecting a `)`, when there's no `(`? Can you file a bug report?

Comment: Seems like the error is for: `query: "name()"; `. what actually do you want to specify here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number for a city you can use a RegEx, too (especially if QML XPath support is not good enough):

```qml
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: container

    width: 360
    height: 360

    Component.onCompleted: {
        loadWeLocationsFile();
    }

    property string weLocationsXML
    signal weLocationsLoaded()

    function loadWeLocationsFile() {
        // load file
        var doc = new XMLHttpRequest();
        doc.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (doc.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                // get file content
                weLocationsXML = doc.responseText;

                // emit signal
                weLocationsLoaded();
            }
        }

        doc.open("GET", "we_locations.plist");
        doc.send();
    }

    function getIDByName(name) {
        // escape special characters for regex (maybe there is a better way to do this)
        var safeName = name.replace(/[-.,?+*#^$()[\]{}\\|]/g, "\\$&");

        // create regex
        var regex = new RegExp("<key>(.*?)</key>\\s*<dict>\\s*<key>NAME</key>\\s*<string>" + safeName + "</string>", "m");

        // execute regex
        var match = regex.exec(weLocationsXML);

        if (match != null && match.length > 1) {
            return match[1];  // name found, group 1 contains id
        } else {
            return null;  // no such name in XML
        }
    }

    // Test it ...
    onWeLocationsLoaded: {
        console.log("Number for 'Algier':", getIDByName("Algier"));
        console.log("Number for 'NotInXML':", getIDByName("NotInXML"));
        console.log("Number for 'Some other city':", getIDByName("Some other city"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Number for 'Algier': 60390
Number for 'NotInXML': null
Number for 'Some other city': 60391
```

If you need the number in a QML model you can create a `ListModel` and add the number to it.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot :). Fixes my problem for now.

Answer (score 5):

**One XPath expression that selects exactly the wanted `key` element is this**:

```
   /*/dict/dict/dict/dict
     /key
        [following-sibling::dict[1]/key
                  [.='NAME'
                 and
                   following-sibling::string[1] = $pCity
                  ]
        ]
```

**When $pCity is set/substituted-by `"Algier"`, this XPath expression selects**:

```
<key>60390</key>
```

**When $pCity is set/substituted-by `"Some other city"`, this XPath expression selects**:

```
<key>60391</key>
```

**XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pCity" select="'Some other city'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "/*/dict/dict/dict/dict
     /key
        [following-sibling::dict[1]/key
                  [.='NAME'
                 and
                   following-sibling::string[1] = $pCity
                  ]
        ]
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied against the provided XML document**:

```
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>en_GB</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Africa</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Algeria</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>60390</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>NAME</key>
                        <string>Algier</string>
                        <key>LATITUDE</key>
                        <string>36.7500</string>
                        <key>LONGITUDE</key>
                        <string>3.0500</string>
                    </dict>
                    <key>60391</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>NAME</key>
                        <string>Some other city</string>
                        <key>LATITUDE</key>
                        <string>36.7500</string>
                        <key>LONGITUDE</key>
                        <string>3.0500</string>
                    </dict>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<key>60391</key>
```

**When in the above transformation we replace**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pCity" select="'Some other city'"/>
```

**with**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pCity" select="'Algier'"/>
```

**and apply the transformation again, then again we get the correct result**:

```
<key>60390</key>
```

Comment: Hmm, Sounds reasonable. Though I'll have to check it up in QML to really mark it as correct answer. I'll up vote in the meanwhile because seems to be working in other tools. :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: @debuggerman: You are welcome. If QML implements XPath (as it should), it should produce the wanted results with this solution.